# Get Method reference from Method object

Tags: java, java-8

I have a method that expects a method reference:

```
expectsMethodRef(obj::someMethod);
```

I now only retrieve the method at compiletime with reflection. How do I get the method reference from a Method object?

```
Method method = obj.class.getMethod(methodNameStr);
expectsMethodRef(<how to input my method here?>);
```

Comment: One is a method reference via a functional interface, the other one is a object which holds some information about a method (at RUNTIME!). Those are completely different things

Comment: I know they are different, that is the reason I cannot just input it there. But there should be a way to transform it?

Comment: There can be no method that accepts just a method reference, only a method that excepts a functional interface, in terms of strictness. If you tell us the type of that interface I could suggest a solution.

Comment: the method actually does expect a interface with one method. Thus the method reference functions as an anonymous interface implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to use `Method.invoke`. Here is an example:

```
public class SomeObject{

    public String someMethod(){
        return "Test";
    }
}

public String expectsMethodRef( Function<SomeObject, String> f ){
    SomeObject so = new SomeObject();
    return f.apply(so);
}
```

And here is how you invoke using plain lambda and Method object.

```
    //plain lmbda
    expectsMethodRef( SomeObject::someMethod  );

    //with method object
    Method someMethod = SomeObject.class.getMethod("someMethod");        
    expectsMethodRef( (so) -> {
        try {
            return (String)someMethod.invoke(so);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    } );
```

Comment: This is a good solution for instance methods. `Function<SomeObject, String>` could be satisfied by a static method a `SomeObject` parameter, too. In that case this approach wouldn't work. Maybe you could check if the method is static? In that case you would just add an additional `null` first parameter to the reflective invocation.

Comment: `Method.invoke` should work in either case. Except in case of static method the `so` object will be ignored. 
The OP example was referring to instance method since it was using `obj::someMethod` syntax.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer :) but why do you cast here `(String)someMethod.invoke(so);`?

Comment: The `invoke` method return Object and needs to be cast to String.